# Copy and Paste on Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am testing a method that generates a one time code each time to complete the testing and this requires the user to copy and paste a number of digits which are randomly generated each time.

The html where the number is generated is the following:

```
<div class="message_text">Enter the following one time code in the field below</div>
<span class="message_label">One-time code:</span>
<span class="message_label">One-time code:</span>
<span class="message_value">720756</span>
```

I wrote this bit of code to copy ands paste and while it does this I keep getting an error stating it is an object.

```
var copyTest = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="core_order_holder"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]'));
                copyTest.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'a');
                copyTest.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'c');
                var target = console.log(copyTest.sendKeys(protractor.Key.CONTROL, 'v'));
                element(by.name('challenge_response')).sendKeys(target);
```

How can I got about fixing this please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that won't work. Copy/paste - is operation system level action, webdriver can't emulate this. But actually - why would you need to test OS? Check only your website features - simple getText() and sendKeys() is totally fine:

```
var copyTest = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="core_order_holder"]/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]')).getText();
element(by.name('challenge_response')).sendKeys(copyTest);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! I had already tried using getText that but for some reason it was still returning an error, that is why I moved to try the copy paste technique